# Freemarker: truncate_c is not working as expected

Tags: java, freemarker

According to docs `truncate_c` should truncate the text at any given place:

> truncate_c will truncate at any character, not just at word ends. For
> example, longName?truncate_c(16) returns "This is a t[...]", rather
> than "This is a [...]" (as saw in earlier example). This tends to give
> a string length closer to the length specified, but still not an exact
> length, as it removes white-space before the terminator string, and
> re-adds a space if we are just after the end of a word, etc.

But it is not working as expected in below case :
So the String I would like to truncate is `1234 SOMESTREETSSS AVE NE 123` So the code is as below

```
<#assign myField = "1234 SOMESTREETSSS AVE NE 123">
${myField?truncate_c(25, '')}
```

Expected output is `1234 SOMESTREETSSS AVE NE`
Actual output is `1234 SOMESTREETSSS AVE N`

I think it is a bug, or I am missing something.

[Link to documentation of truncate](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_truncate)

Comment: This issue has been resolved, please read here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FREEMARKER-219

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's a bug. Will certainly fix it for 2.3.33. Until that, you can provide a fixed algorithm with the `truncate_builtin_algorithm` configuration setting as a workaround.

**Update:** Reading the documentation, it turns out that these are actually the expected results, but are rather anti-intuitive if your terminator string is `''`. To improve that, now if the terminator length is 0, 2.3.33 doesn't add a separator space before the terminator string anymore (normally we do add that if the cut was at a word boundary). But, it still trims at the cut. I suspect what you want is actually `myField[0 ..* 25]`, as that does no tricks to make the output nicer for human readers.

Comment: Hey @ddekany, thank you for fast response. Is there any doc or guide which I can follow. Thanks.

Comment: @mipasov The Javadoc (https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/TruncateBuiltinAlgorithm.html), but probably you just want to copy, rename and modify the `DefaultTruncateBuiltinAlgorithm` from the source code.